# Haskell: Filter List with those that are Integers

Tags: list, haskell, filter

How would I filter a list so that I only return the list of those that are integers?

For example, filtering a list like `[1, 1.2, 2, 2.2]` would return `[1, 2]`.

Comment: There is no `Integer` in this list. A list has only elements of the same type, so here if there's a double all are doubles for example.

Comment: Why do you need this? If you provide a bit of context, we can give answers that suit your problem better.

Comment: If you want to ignore non-integers from some user input, you'd be better solving this problem while the data is still a string. Notice that in general, a floating point number _can't_ be tested for equality, because the representation is inaccurate, so you can only test for approximate equality, and you'd have to decide how close is close enough. That's why one of the answers uses the `Fractional` class - they're stored as exact representations, so can be tested for equality and whether thay're integers or not.

Answer (score 6):

Considering your list to be of type `[Double]` as you can not have (in any simple way) a list with elements of different types.

Once you have a list of double, you can use the function `ceiling`.

```
ceiling 2.1 = 3
ceiling 2.0 = 2
```

so a function to check if a number has no fractional part can be written as

```
nonFractional d = (fromIntegral $ ceiling d) == d
```

now you can do filter on this

```
> filter nonFractional [1, 1.2, 2, 2.2]
[1.0,2.0]
```

(Edit) 
The above approach of comparing equality does not work for large numbers like

```
> nonFractional  (12345678987654321.5)
True
```

Using @David's idea if you change the definition of `nonFractional` as

```
nonFractional d = (fromIntegral $ ceiling d :: Rational) == d
```

Then it seems to work for large fractions as well

```
> nonFractional  (12345678987654321.5)
True
```

Comment: `Prelude> properFraction (12345678987654321.5)` gave 
`(12345678987654322,0.0)`. So it is the case as well with properFraction.

Comment: What about `(fromIntegral $ ceiling d :: Rational) == d` ?

Comment: @AndrewC : David's  approach seems to work. I have corrected the code reflecting that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17122/discussion-between-andrewc-and-daniel-fischer)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, your list should be homogenous, so you can't have list of `Integer`s and `Doubles`.

There is a nice function `properFraction`, which decomposes a number into its whole and fractional parts:

```
properFraction :: (Fractional a, Integral b) => a -> (b,a)
```

So, we can define a function to figure out is number have a non-zero fractional part or not.

```
> let haveNoFractionalPart = (== 0.0) . snd . properFraction 
haveNoFractionalPart :: Double -> Bool
```

No we can filter your list with that function:

```
> filter haveNoFractionalPart [1, 1.2, 2, 2.2]
[1.0,2.0]
```

---

**Update**:

I should admit that my solution isn't valid and workable for some cases in the real world. Because of something like

```
> properFraction (11111111111111111111.1)
(11111111111111110656,0.0)
```

Anyway, it's hard to imagine the case when it's needed to filter what you calling an `Integer` from some list of values that you have. And there is no such way to define that any number with floating point have zero floating part with 100% probability.

Maybe some wrapper over `Integer` and `Double` will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
filterInt :: (RealFrac a) => [a] -> [Integer]
filterInt [] = []
filterInt (x:xs)
    | frac == 0 = a : filterInt xs
    | otherwise = filterInt xs
  where
      (a, frac) = properFraction x
```

test:

```
> let li = [1, 1.2, 2, 2.2]
> filterInt li
> [1,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

A number of solutions have been posted for `Rational`, where in actuality you really only need to compare the denominator to 1:

```
hasFraction' :: Rational -> Bool
hasFraction' = (/= 1) . denominator
```

This can be generalized to any `Real` and is one of the safest methods to check whether a number has a fractional part:

```
hasFraction :: (Real a) => a -> Bool
hasFraction = hasFraction' . toRational
```

That function does not solve the rounding error problem, but that's natural.  When rounding errors bother you, you're using the wrong data type.

Comment: " When rounding errors bother you, you're using the wrong data type." Absolutely. Make sure you know when it's bothering you because it might quietly "work" whilst editing all your data.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you got the data from.

Haskell doesn't let you mix pure integers with non-integers, 
so your integers will get tainted with the inaccuracy inherent in data types like `Double` unless you use something more accurate like `Rational`, 
but given that you don't want the non-integers anyway, throw them away at source, before they're numeric data, if you can.

- If you got the data from a user, either use an input form that only allows them to enter sequences of digits, or use `getInt` below.
- If you got the data from a database or other text-based source, use `getInt` below.
- If you got the data from some code you don't control (library or external call), is there an alternative that will give you just integers?
  If so, use it, if not, use one of the other rounding-based solutions in the other answers.

`getInt` converts a String to an Integer, cunningly ignoring anything that isn't an Integer:

```
import Data.Char (isDigit)

getInt :: String -> Maybe Integer
getInt xs | all isDigit xs = Just (read xs)
          | otherwise      = Nothing
```

So `getInt "12345"` is `Just 12345` whereas `getInt 12345678987654321.1` is `Nothing`. 
We can use that to remove non-integer input from some list:

```
getInts :: [String] -> [Integer]
getInts xss = catMaybes $ map getInt xss
```

or more consisely, we could write
`getInts = catMaybes.map getInt`.

Now `catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]` and it gets rid of the `Nothing`s and unwraps the `Just`s. We'll need to
`import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)` at the top to get it.

If your data comes as a floating point number of some sort, 
bear in mind there's no true equality in a floating point type, 
so even if you convert to a more accurate representation before checking, 
it's logically impossible for you to ever know whether the original data 
represented an exact integer or just something quite close to an integer 
that the floating point representation rounded before the data got to you. 
For example:

```
Prelude> (12345678987654321.6 :: Double) == 12345678987654322.0
True
```

whereas

```
Prelude> (12345678987654321.6 :: Rational) == 12345678987654322.0
False
```

But if you can choose the data type, you're in control of the generating code, so choose not to include non-integers!

Summary: it's easiest to get rid of non-integers *before* you turn them into numerical data, 
and you're not subject to occasional bizzare rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your list will have to be of type `[Double]` or `[Integer]`, or some other type of number. You cannot mix types.

That said, if you have a list of doubles and you're trying to filter out those that are not integers, you can always use `round`, `floor`, or `ceiling` to check equivalency to the number.

For example:

```
isInt :: (RealFrac a) => a -> Bool
isInt x = x == (fromIntegral $ round x)
```

Then you can just filter your data using this, using `filter`:

```
filter isInt [1, 1.2, 2, 2.2] -- [1.0, 2.0]
```